# How to set app.yaml variable on github actions/GPC

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, github-actions, app.yaml

I have an application made on TypeScript, deployed by GitHub Actions, hosted on Firebase - Google Cloud.

I need set the `"instance_class: B4"` dynamic depending of environment

I have 3 environments DEV, QA and PROD and I want to specify which type of server will start on each.

I have some variables on gitHub and some secrets on GPC, but I don't know which and how to use.

How can I change `app.yaml` on deploy process?

Thanks

[image: App.yaml]

Answer (score 2):

See [Using a matrix for your jobs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-a-matrix-for-your-jobs) to configure your GitHub Action to deploy to your 3 environments.

Then you've choices:

1. Multiple `app.yaml`'s (one per environment)

   - Advantage: simple
   - Disadvantage: requires you to ensure the other values remain unchanged.
2. One `app.yaml`

   - Advantage: more accurately (!?) reflects the intent
   - Disadvantage: requires you to add YAML processing (e.g. [`yq`](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq)) to your actions